constructing new types
This is probably a very stupid question but google does not get me anywhere. I am wondering, how to construct new Types in Lean 4. For example, if i want to have a structure that only contains the cartesian product of positive floats, i need that Type in the first place. In essence i am wondering about how to just consider elements of some type that satisfy some constraints, for example an equation.

Does Subtype fit your need?

To answer your title question, there are many ways to make new types in Lean.  Here are four ways for your specific use case (pair of positive floats):
import Init.Data.Float

-- Structure type
structure MyStructureType where
  x : Float
  y : Float
  x_positive: x > 0
  y_positive: y > 0

-- Subtype
def MySubtype := {p : Float × Float // p.1 > 0.0 ∧ p.2 > 0.0}

-- Cartesian product of other types
def PosFloat := {x : Float // x > 0.0}
def MyProdType := PosFloat × PosFloat

Some comments:

If your type just contains data, then a structure type is a natural fit.  Notice that data can be more traditional forms of data (like floats) as well as proofs about that data.  (The proofs are not actually stored by Lean, but are needed to be able to construct an object of that type.)  They form a role similar to dataclasses or structs in other languages.
Two special cases of structure types are subtypes and Cartesian products.  A  subtype restricts another type to only those elements that satisfy a given property.  A Cartesian product is a pair of elements from two other types. (Both are implemented underneath as structure types).  One advantage of using these is that if your application is simple enough, you may not even need to make your own custom type.

Just to be more complete, there are more ways to make types in Lean. Here are two other ways, but not well suited for your application:
-- Function type
def MyFunType := Bool -> PosFloat

-- Inductive type
inductive MyInductiveType
| mk (x: Float) (y: Float) (x_pos: x > 0) (y_pos: y > 0)


Function types are exactly that, the type of functions from A to B.  In your case, sometimes it is useful to think of a series of objects as a function from the index to the value for that index.  Since Bool has two elements, each such function represents a pair.  This trick is helpful in mathematics, especially when the series is infinite.
Inductive types are a generalization of structures.  They are more useful when the type is inductive (like a tree) or when there are different cases for the type (like Enum types).

